# How to parse url parameter in node js request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i am pass a url as parameter like

```js
http://localhost:1337/getData?url=%22https://dramaonline.com/%22&type=%22channellist%22
```

and then using it in node js for my function inputs

```js
var typeValue = req.query.type;
    var urlValue = req.query.url;    
     
    var resultsFromFunction;
    request(urlValue, function (error, response, html) {
        
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            if (typeValue.toString().match('channellist')) { 
            
            
            
                resultsFromFunction = users.channelList(html);
            }
             
                res.end(JSON.stringify(resultsFromFunction));

        }
        else {
            console.log('\nShowing error...\n');
            console.log(error);
        }
            
    });
   
});
```

whenever i hit the request it show invalid uri , while passing url in request few parameter like %22 goes with link . how can i parse the url without these charater

Answer (score 0):

You can use `decodeURIComponent(value)` to get rid of these escape sequences:

```
decodeURIComponent('%22https://dramaonline.com/%22&type=%22channellist%22')
// ""https://dramaonline.com/"&type="channellist""
```